# How can we listen to the event of volume button press in when the screen is not active in React native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, event-handling

I know there must be some solution available for this. Because in native apps I have done this but I haven't found the way to do it in React native.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [volume manager library](https://github.com/hirbod/react-native-volume-manager)

usage:

```
import { VolumeManager } from 'react-native-volume-manager';


const volumeListener = VolumeManager.addVolumeListener((result) => {
  console.log(result.volume);

  // On Android, additional volume types are available:
  // music, system, ring, alarm, notification
});
```

Comment: Does this work while the screen is off and the application is in background stage?

Comment: yes when app not killed, try run the example